# Saturated Density Plots

Tags: plotting

I am making some density and contour plots in Mathematica. These plots have very high peaks which saturate with color and prevent me from seeing differences in the peaks. Is there a way I can tone down the color scale so my peaks are not just white blobs?

Trying other color schemes has not worked out, and playing with the range of color data has not been very useful. Is there some way to have the colors on a log scale???

Here is my code.

```
ListDensityPlot[photo, PlotLegends -> Automatic, Frame -> {True}, 
FrameLabel -> {"Electron Bunch Energy (MeV)", "Photon Energy (keV)", 
"", "Yield (Photons/Sr e-KeV)" }, LabelStyle -> {15}, 
InterpolationOrder -> 10]
```

[image]

Cheers, Ben

Comment: Have you tried `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` ?

Comment: How about plotting `Log[photo]` instead?

Comment: Welcome, Ben.  I have added your image.  I would be very helpful if you could include the `photo` data or something smaller that is representative.

Comment: photo is a table of data with 3 columns, taking log[photo] does not work well, but maybe if I could just take the log of the third column. Any thought on how to do this? (I am very new to mathematica)

Comment: Here are a few lines of the table. There are close to one hundred thousand so i cant show all the data.

{3.5,   0.0006134358411192535, 3.1844733006569277e-6}  {3.5, 1.145284962069662, 0.009472220083431099}  {3.6, 4.081632653061224e-8, 3.286096736383321e-6}  {3.6, 1.1968482343523787  0.009240961411244974}

The difficulty lies in the drastic range of values for the third column.

Comment: `{#, #2, Log@#3} & @@@ data` or `MapAt[Log, data, {All, 3}]`

Comment: Not enough data.

Comment: @Kuba Boy, I am trying to use the MapAt function, how would I make it Log base 10 instead of Log (which is base e)?

Comment: it usualy faster to ask such question to documentation center :) There are cross links from `Log` to `Log10`, `Log2` etc., not to mention that at the top there is `Log[b, z]`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's difficult to help without `photo` data, but I'm almost sure that `PlotRange` can solve your problem.
Try to control Z coordinate in PlotRange as in this example, to find a better range to your plot.

```
pSaturated=DensityPlot[Exp[-10(x^2+y^2)],{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},ImageSize->400];
pOK=DensityPlot[Exp[-10(x^2+y^2)],{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},PlotRange->{All,All,{0,1}},ImageSize->400];
Row[{pSaturated,pOK}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful but by limiting my plotting range I would be losing information. But, I appreciate the thought!

Comment: You are not limiting you are extending for beyond the saturation zone. :)

Comment: This worked out very well, I was able to make some excellent plots! Any thoughts on how to get rid of the the discontinuous nature and extrapolate the plot?

Comment: I'm glad that it has helped you! Maybe in `PlotRange->{All,All,{0,1}}` you can make it more generic using `PlotRange->{All,All,{0,Max[photo[[All,3]]]}}`.

Comment: As @Kuba suggests `PlotRange->All` is much more elegant. See if it works for you. There are some cases that it's necessary to specify manually.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing Murta's data we can also try out [Rahul Narain](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/484/rahul-narain)'s `Log` recommendation:

```
data = Table[Exp[-10 (x^2 + y^2)], {x, -1, 1, 0.02}, {y, -1, 1, 0.02}];

ListDensityPlot[data]

ListDensityPlot[Log @ data]
```

[image] [image]

If your data is in the (x,y,z) form you will need something like `{#, #2, Log@#3} & @@@ data` as Kuba comments above.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay but I had net gap.

I wanted to write that sometimes *Mathematica* is doing things we are not expecting in order to do them fast for example.

It seems in this case default `ColorFunctionScalling` is not so bad, it's just the issue of not all is plotted.

Sometimes it is also useful to choose more colorful palette:

```
data = Table[{x, y, 10^6 Exp[-10 (x^2 + y^2)]}, {x, -1, 1, 0.02}, {y, -1, 1, 0.02}
            ] // Flatten[#, 1] &;

SetOptions[ListDensityPlot, ImageSize -> 250]

GraphicsRow[{
   ListDensityPlot[data],
   ListDensityPlot[data, PlotRange -> All],
   ListDensityPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
   }]
```

So basicaly it is what @Murta showed but without checking the range.

[image]